# MoSync Reload captureImage working on html but not in webview

Tags: html, webview, reload

I have a html page that uses the camera on my iphone and returns an alert. It works fine as a web app but when i try to use native ui webview the camera still gets called but there is no alert. Any idea why?

```
 function getImage()
 {
     navigator.device.capture.captureImage(      
        function(success){
            alert('getImageSuccess');
        },          
        function(error){
            alert('getImageFailure');
        }
    );

 }
```